# Unable to understand why the worst case of merge sort takes $(n\log_2{(n) - 1}) + 1$ steps

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am trying to count the number of steps taken by merge sort in the worst case, but I keep arriving at $(n-1)\log_2{(n)}$ steps for the worst input.

But it seems according to [formal texts the correct answer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3210) is $(n\log_2{(n) - 1}) + 1$.

This doesn't make sense to me for a number of reasons.

**First** $\log_2{(n)} - 1$ means that the depth of the **merge tree decrease by 1.** How is that possible? *The number of levels in merge sort are always the same regardless of the worst or best input.* Right?

**Second**, what is the $+1$ at the end. What is that there for ?

Let me show an example that I used for my calculations to illustrate my point:

```
{7,3,9,5,8,4,10,6}

{3,7} {5,9} {4,8} {6,10}

{3,5,7,9} {4,6,8,10}

{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

At each stage after the first one each merge operations seems to make $n1 + n2 - 1$ comparisions, where $n1$ and $n2$ are the sizes of each list. **The depth of the tree does not decrease.**

And I have no idea on how that $+1$ is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result $(n-1)\log n$ and the text's $(n\log n - 1) + 1$ (which is just $n\log n$, but that may be a typo) both have the same asymptotic growth. In algorithmic analysis you would call them both $\Theta(n\log n)$.

The precise totals beyond the asymptotic growth is extremely sensitive to exactly what you consider as a "step" in the algorithm that deserves counting? For example, it could easily make a difference of $n$ whether you consider "sort a one-element list" at the bottom of the call tree to be an operation that deserves counting.

---

A bit of less shaky ground can be found by counting **comparisons**. Then each element passes through $\log n$ merge steps, which gives us an $n\log n$ term, since each time an element comes out of a merge step it consumes a comparison. Except, that is, that the *last* element in each merged list can always be emitted without comparing it to anything, saving $n-1$ comparisons (your can count the total amount of list merges by noticing that each of them reduces the total number of lists you have in play by $1$ -- and you start with $n$ lists and end with a single one).

This analysis ends up with $$n\log n - (n - 1) = n\log n - n + 1 = n(\log n - 1) + 1$$ comparisons in the worst case.

---

If you're counting comparisons too, then how do you conclude there should be $(n-1)\log n$ of them? In the concrete example you show, you have $n=8$ and need $1+1+1+1+3+3+7=17$ comparisons, but $(n-1)\log n$ is $21$.

Hmm, it seems like you may be thinking the $-1$ in $n_1+n_2-1$ only saves you a comparison *per layer*, but it's really *per list*. This that means that each layer where more than one list is produced has some savings that you're not accounting for.